# Luggage storage in Bucharest

Tags: luggage-storage, short-notice, bucharest

I'm visiting a friend in Bucharest, I will arrive at the airport in the morning, they wont be home until night time, I don't want to carry my luggage around with me all day, so I need somewhere to leave it for several hours, I will pick it up on the same day, what are my options?

I found [Luggage Lockers/Storage](http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g294458-i3832-k4403016-Luggage_Lockers_Storage-Bucharest.html)  posted in 2011, that says "Unfortunately there aren't any places around Piata Unirii where you could leave your luggage" , and [Luggage storage](http://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g294458-i3832-k5234777-Luggage_storage-Bucharest.html)  posted in 2012 on TripAdvisor, both mentions that Gare de Nord has a luggage storage office, I'm considering that as a last resort, but I'd prefer something more central closer to Piața Unirii or one of the large shopping malls

Comment: The first reply in that thread says *"Unfortunately there aren't any places around Piata Unirii where you could leave your luggage"*

Comment: @blackbird57 I'm hoping things have changed since that was posted

Answer (score 2):

[The Man in Seat 61 says that there is luggage storage in Gara de Nord](http://www.seat61.com/luggage-lockers-at-stations.htm#Left_luggage_offices_&_lockers_in_other_European_cities):

> **Bucharest**:  Left luggage office at Bucharest Gara de Nord, 50m past the Relay newsagents.  4 Lei (around €1) per 24 hours.  No lockers or left luggage office visible at Brasov.  There's reportedly now a staffed left luggage service at Sighisoara station, 7 lei per 24h.

Comment: Sighisoara is a different city (as is Brasov); the Seat61 paragraph is confusingly formatted, but only the first sentence refers to Bucharest.

Answer (score 0):

There is a luggage storage facility in City Center, open 7 days a week. The address is 24 Coltei Street and it costs 3 Euros / 3 hours. Their website is www.bucharestluggagestorage.com

Comment: Do you have any more information? Cost? Precise location? Website?

Comment: the address is Coltei Street no.24 ;price whitin 3 hours / 3 Euros

Comment: Good. Add this to the answer. :)

Comment: www.bucharestluggagestorage.com

Comment: Is this your company?

Comment: :)good question!

Comment: If you are in any way affiliated with the company you should say so. Or else your answer will be deleted because of spam.

Comment: I have visited the location,few days ago,it is in my way,and I've got a flyer.